# Automatically Shade Window on Unfocus

Tags: window-manager, window-management, xfce4

I have certain windows (for example, Empathy) that I want to be automatically roll up (or shade) upon being unfocused and to roll down (or un-shade) when focused. I can manually roll the windows up and when focus returns, they roll down. However, when they lose focus again, they do not roll back up.

Is there a way to enable this behavior?

I know that I can execute the following command to shade the active window, but I don't know how to cause such a command to trigger on unfocus.

```
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b "add,shaded"
```

Switching to a different window manager, such as Compiz, is an option if it is capable of providing such behavior and interacting with XFCE. I'm currently using XFCE 4.10 with XFWM4.